# Получить значение из двумерного массива

Tags: php, массивы

var_dump($json) показывает так:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (19) {
    ["action_type"]=>
    NULL
    ["button_num"]=>
    NULL
    ["call_id"]=>
    int(200403597922495)
и т.д.
```

Как получить в переменную значение

```
$call_id = $json->{'call_id'};
$call_id = $json[0]['call_id']   // не работает
```

Comment: `$call_id = $json[0]->call_id`

Comment: спасибо, заработало